# How to avoid a long server interruption when I renew MQTT SSL certificate

Tags: thingsboard

I hope to reduce a server interruption when I renew MQTT SSL certificate.
And I am interested about how to reduce it in Thingsboard Cloud.

I use Thingsboard PE on AWS.
I finished a setting of HA Proxy and MQTT SSL.

I checked a time of restart of HA Proxy for HTTP SSL certificate renewal.
It takes less than 1sec.

I checked a time of restart of thingsboard for MQTT SSL certificate renewal by "service thingsboard restart".
It takes about 50sec.

I hope to reduce the 50sec.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are using a ec2 instance to handle your TB PE service, I think to set new SSL configuration you cant avoid this restart so you must have another instance running until your modifications are applied (you can use load balancer to redirect your traffic), note that you may have to modify your PE license in licence portal if you want to use the same licence for multiple nodes.

You can consider deploy your thingsboard service in EKS if continuous operation is very important for you, where you can have more than one node running by same time and in different regions: https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/pe/cluster/aws-eks-setup/

Comment: By having more than one instance you must move your database to a RDS, otherwise each instance will have its own database

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I need to find the best solution.